# How should I keep track of my financial assets across borders and currencies?

Tags: currency, international, software, assets, tracking

I'm an expat and am curious: Is there any better way out there to manage my various assets in differing currencies across borders and markets? Currently, I just use a spreadsheet, but it is becoming difficult to manage.

Comment: You tagged your question "asset-allocation". Are you referring specifically to *investments*, or all/other kinds of assets (bank accounts, properties, etc.?) Could you elaborate on your goals?

Comment: All, more of a general thing, I keep a spreadsheet with all my investments, including property values, stocks, cash, etc. Looking for an easy way to manage it all. Asset allocation may not be completely accurate, sorry if it is not. The problem is managing multiple currencies, it gets messy / lots of different things/markets to lookup / track.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea lulz, "we bear no specification!" is our motto?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using software capable of doing this automatically would make this process less onerous.

Still, each asset should be marked in its respective currency of denomination, and translated later for reporting, e.g. a U.S. house should be marked in USD, a U.S. mortgage in USD, a European house in EUR, a European mortgage in EUR, etc.

From there, in the spreadsheet or software, all of the currency cross rates can be updated and applied to each asset. Then, the total value could be seen in each currency of interest.

Comment: Thanks for putting me on all-time rep front page, upvoter!  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6qJ1E8EljVM

Comment: @Louis Sorry about my late upvote. :/